# How to show dialog box with image inside upon hover of mouse over glyphicon

Tags: html

I am looking to display an image when the user hovers over the icon. Currently all it does is, it lets you click on the icon and it will open a new tab with image.

Current code:

```
      html += $"{(question.id == 6 ? "<a href=' ../images/feelsgoodman.png' target='_blank'><img src='../images/chad.svg' class='normielife' data-tip='Click here to view image'><a/>" : "" )}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
<a>Some Link
  <div><img src="/you/image" /></div>
</a>
```

Then:

```
a>div { display: none; }
a:hover>div { display: block; }
```